# Adding text (sample size) on top of stacked bar chart returns error message in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

Current figure: [image: Current figure]
Desired effect: [image: Desired effect]

I have a stacked bar chart which I wanted to add sample size on top of the chart, I tried using geomtext with the following code:

```
Data %>% count(Month, Age) %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  mutate(percent = n/sum(n)*100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, percent, fill = as.factor(Age))) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") + ylab("") +
  geom_text(aes(label = n_month, y = 1.05)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#E69F00", "#0072B2")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 17), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10), size = 16))
```

This returns an error, which I understand that it's because there are actually 34 data in this figure, but I only wanted it to display 12 numbers. For now I can only succeed if there's only 12 data (Hence the "Desired effect" figure). How should I change my code?

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (34): label"
```

```
n_month
 [1] 18  8 20 18 24 34 32 15 22 26 12 13
```

Comment: Issue: You are setting up the y in the `ggplot(aes(...))` and define a new one in `geom_text()`.  Solution: either you define your `aes(Month, percent, fill = as.factor(Age))` in `geom_col()` or you delete the `aes()` in `geom_text()` and work with eg `vjust = -0.5`

Comment: I don't know if I misunderstood anything, but I tried changing into `geom_text(label = n_month, vjust = -0.5)`, but it still returns the error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (34): label.

Comment: Alternatively I tried `ggplot() +  geom_col(aes(Month, percent, fill = as.factor(Age)), position = "fill") ` without changing the code in geom_text, but the error remains the same. I apologize if I overlooked something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the delay. I tried to reproduce your data and the issue is the underlying data. For your approach it would be easier to have different datasets for your geoms.

For this example I am using the `nycflights13` data, which is probably similar to your data.

Here is my setup:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(nycflights13)

graph_data <- flights %>% 
  filter(carrier %in% c("UA", "B6", "EV")) %>% 
  count(carrier, month) %>% 
  add_count(month, wt = n, name = "n_month") %>% 
  mutate(percent = n / n_month * 100)
```

Data looks like:

```
# A tibble: 36 × 3
   carrier month     n n_month percent
   <chr>   <int> <int>   <int>   <dbl>
 1 B6          1  4427   13235    33.4
 2 B6          2  4103   12276    33.4
 3 B6          3  4772   14469    33.0
```

Now we supply the `geom_col()` and `geom_text()` with different datasets, based on your `graph_data`.

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_col(
    data = graph_data,
    aes(x = month, y = percent, fill = as.factor(carrier)), 
    position = "fill") + ylab("") +
  geom_text(
    data = distinct(graph_data, month, n_month),
    aes(x = month, y = 1.05, label = n_month)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#E69F00", "#0072B2")) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 17), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10), size = 16))
```

I tried to leave your code as much as possible, just added the `data = ...` argument in the `geom_`s.

Output is:

[image]

Comment: you can all `+ scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 1), breaks = c(1:12))`